# cant get the value of a readonly textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, compiler-errors, readonly-attribute

i have an asp,net textbox like this

```
<asp:TextBox readonly="true" ID="txtLastService" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

when i tried to get its value to a date variable LastService in code behind, i get this error

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.
>
> Exception
>   Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to
>   type 'Date' is not valid.
>   Source Error:  Line 26:         oItem.LastService = txtLastService.Text Source File: .\admin\vehicle\add.aspx.vb    Line:
>   26

i have used this same code in other pages, and it works fine, except for this page
any help

EDIt

Please note that the value of the textbox is not empty when i click submit on the form. And also when i remove the readonly attributes, i don;t get the error. But i need this textbox to be readonly since am using javascript to select date and setting its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Readonly="true"`, try using `Enabled="false"`

Answer (score 1):

The error seems extremely self-explanatory to me. The string is "" and you are trying to convert it to a Date. So how the heck can an empty string be converted to a Date? What date would that be?

Comment: the value of the textbox is not empty

Comment: It is according to the details you've provided. Set a breakpoint in the debugger. What is the value exactly? Where are you reading the value in your code? Define the issue if you want to resolve it.

Comment: the value of the textbox when filled in browser is a date string mm/dd/yyyy. but i don't get this value in the server. am reading the value in the server from the code behind. i want to get the value of the textbox in the server

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`HiddenField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) instead?

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="txtLastService" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: the textbox has to be visible, as am musing java script to set the value which is a date

Answer (score 0):

Try using Request.Form[txtLastService.UniqueID] if C# and
Request.Form(txtLastService.UniqueID) if vb.net